# How to see embedding from an algebraic point of view?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

There is a classical statement that a nonorientable closed surface can’t be embedded in $R^3$. And we can proof a weaker statement by Mayer-Vietoris sequence: a closed nonorientable surface $X$ has no neighborhood which is homeomorphism to a mapping cylinder of $f$, where $f$ is a map from a closed orientable surface to $X$ ($H_1(X)$ will has torsion and leads to contradiction in Mayer-Vietoris sequence).

So I am wondering how to see “embedding” with algebraic point of view like the argument above? Intuitively, a geometry interpretation of embedding is that a surface doesn’t intersect itself in a certain space(a Klein bottle must intersects itself in $R^3$, but can be embedded in $R^4$). But it’s hard to write down this idea in the language of mathematics.

I know in Algebraic Geometry, embedding is defined as a surjective morphism of sheaf of rings, which provides a more manageable way to identify “embedding”. And intersection theory may be also a way to deal with “embedding”.

More theories may be needed to handle this question, and I want to know the ideas behind those theories. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. What do you mean "... it's hard to write down this idea in the language of mathematics"? Avoiding self-intersection is easy: you just require injectivity of the embedding. 2. Your definition of closed embedding in algebraic geometry is incomplete: a closed embedding $X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism from the underlying topological space of $X$ to it's image (a closed subset of $Y$) plus the condition on sheaves of rings you mention.